# What can cause "Network interfaces and instance-level security groups may not be specified on the same request" when using launch templates?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm getting

```
╷
│ Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: Network interfaces and an instance-level security groups may not be specified on the same request
│       status code: 400, request id: 97729886-6941-430d-9e6b-86b756710c6b
│
```

The `aws_instance` references a `aws_launch_template` but as far as I know the launch template  and instance definition do not have conflicting setting regarding the security groups, I even removed all security group references from both the launch template and instance and I still get the same error.

What else can be the source of this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always try to create the EC2 instance from the AWS console with "Launch instance from template" and usually get a better indication of what is the underlying problem.

In particular check that you `aws_instance` is using the **$Latest** version of your `aws_launch_template` and not `$Default` which is usually version 1 and not the latest.

```
resource "aws_instance" "xxxx" {
  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.yyyy.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }

...
```

Otherwise you may be trying with an older version of the launch template that actually is specifying security groups at both the network interface level and instance level.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you, the problem was that my launch_template definition was using the attribute vpc_security_group_ids and then the instance was trying to set the subnets, my configuration was like this

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "static_launch_template" {
  provider = aws.master_region
  name = "static_launch_template"
  image_id = data.aws_ami.base_ami.image_id
  instance_type = var.static_instance_type
  iam_instance_profile {
    arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.static_instance_profile.arn
  }
  user_data = filebase64("webconfig/user-data-static.sh")
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.static_security_group.id]
  metadata_options {
    http_endpoint = "enabled"
    http_tokens = "required"
    instance_metadata_tags = "enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "static_instance" {
  provider = aws.master_region
  count = var.static_instance_count
  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.static_launch_template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
  tags = {
    "Number": count.index
    "Owner": "load_balancer"
  }
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_subnets[count.index % length(aws_subnet.public_subnets)].id
}
```

Solved the problem by using the network_interface configuration in the launch_template like this

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "static_launch_template" {
  provider = aws.master_region
  name = "static_launch_template"
  image_id = data.aws_ami.base_ami.image_id
  instance_type = var.static_instance_type
  iam_instance_profile {
    arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.static_instance_profile.arn
  }
  network_interfaces {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.static_security_group.id]
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    delete_on_termination =true
  }
  user_data = filebase64("webconfig/user-data-static.sh")
  metadata_options {
    http_endpoint = "enabled"
    http_tokens = "required"
    instance_metadata_tags = "enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "static_instance" {
  provider = aws.master_region
  count = var.static_instance_count
  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.static_launch_template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
  tags = {
    "Number": count.index
    "Owner": "load_balancer"
  }
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_subnets[count.index % length(aws_subnet.public_subnets)].id
}
```